# How can I make Attacks of Opportunity using a ranged weapon?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, opportunity-attack

Is there any way a character can make an attack of opportunity using a ranged weapon?
If so, how?
What book does it come from?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to way to make attacks of opportunity (AoOs from now on) using a ranged weapon. In fact, there are several, which I'm going to detail.
I'm including 3e sources in this answer, since they're still valid in 3.5e

### Use a throwing weapon

Any throwing weapon can be used in melee with no penalty. This is the trivial solution.
Of course, throwing weapons have a short range increment, each "ammunition" is heavy and costy and every single weapon must be enchanted separately, making this a subpar choice for the vast majority of ranged weapon builds.

### Attacks of Opportunity *while* wielding a ranged weapon

There are several ways to have a melee weapon ready for dealing AoOs even while you're using a two-handed projectile weapon.

The first one is being able to use a weapon with a different part of your body, including but not limited to:

- natural weapons (except claws, but keep reading for those)
- hidden blades (*Complete Scoundrel*)
- armor spikes/razors (*PHB*/*Underdark*)
- braid blade (*Dungeon Magazine #120*, except if it's ruled to be only useable during complete attacks)
- Improved Unarmed Strike (*PHB* feat)
- *Bracers of Striking* (*Magic of Faerun*)

When you wield a two handed weapon, including a bow, you can change your grip to just hold it in your off-hand as a free action, allowing you to attack with your free hand:

- claw attacks
- spiked gauntlets (*PHB*)
- gnomish quick razor (*Races of Stone*)
- drawing a weapon with Quick Draw (*PHB*) or one *Crystal of Return* (*Magic Item Compendium*) per weapon and discarding it before using the bow again (works better with an *unseen servant* picking up the weapon and sheating it again for you)
- switching weapons thanks to two *Gloves of Storing* (*DMG*), the cheaper *Gloves of the Master Strategist* (*Ghostwalk*) or similar items

### Attacks of Opportunity made with a ranged weapon

Some bows from *Races of the Wild* are built to double as melee weapons:

- any elvencraft bow also counts as a nonmagical quarterstaff
- three different weapons grouped under the *Swordbow* name. Keep in mind that the most useful weapon enchantments for ranged weapons (*Splitting* comes to mind) are useless on the blade shape

Some ways to do a ranged AoO:

- 8 levels in the Peerless Archer PrC (*Silver Marches*), 5' range
- the *arrow mind* spell (*Complete Adventurer*/*Spell Compendium*), possibly from a wand or an eternal wand (*Magic Item Compendium*) stored in a wand chamber (*Dungeonscape*), 5' range
- Ranged Threat feat (Dragon Magazine #350) - awful prerequisites but allows one AoO per round up to a 15' range

These options are not guaranteed to prevent people at the right distance to make an AoO against your using a ranged weapon in melee.

Comment: I would have made the word "wielding" italic.

Answer (score 7):

#### *Arrow Mind*

*Spell Compendium* pg. 15-16, Ranger 1st, Sor/Wiz 1st.

Cast as an immediate action and lasting for 1 minute/level, which is *excellent*. It also allows you to shoot a ranged weapon while in melee without provoking. However, attacks of opportunity with ranged weapons are limited to your usual melee reach even with this spell.

I know of no spell that allows you to make attacks of opportunity at the a larger range with a ranged weapon.